# Using database connections in ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro (arcgispro-py3)?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-pro

Since Pro stores database connections in a project, how do we connect to a database from within a standalone python script?

For example below is how I would have previously connected in ArcGIS 10.5

```
import arcpy

GDB_directory = r"C:\Python Testing"
targetEntGDB = r"Database Connections/espr1sql14.sde/"
extractedGDB = "600150be54a84779a461d4fc37247f91.gdb"
extractedGDB = GDB_directory + "\\" +extractedGDB

arcpy.Copy_management(extractedGDB, targetEntGDB)
```

Comment: Cross-posted to [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/211135-database-connections-in-arcgispro-py3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap, it doesn't matter, they both save the .SDE file to an actual place on disk. In ArcMap `Database Connections` maps to a real place on your computer. A connection file created in ArcGIS Pro is still pointing to a real .sde file some where on disk (typically the same directory the project was created in).

To answer your question

> how do we connect to a database from within a standalone python script?

You point your code directly to the connection file. I'd actually **discourage** building a path using `Database Connections` like you are. You can't guarantee that path will exist or that Python can resolve that path. You can't safely take code using that, put it on another computer and know the .SDE file will exist / be found.

Simply,

```
import arcpy

sdeFile = r"C:\Python Testing\SDEFiles\espr1sql14.sde"
extractedGDB = "600150be54a84779a461d4fc37247f91.gdb"
extractedGDB = GDB_directory + "\\" +extractedGDB

arcpy.Copy_management(extractedGDB, sdeFile)
```